# Kali Linux Firewalls and Endpoint security

Tags: kali-linux

I was asked to explain why Kali Linux does not have any firewalls or endpoint security. I would appreciate any help as I am a complete beginner to Kali Linux.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain your own understanding first so that we know where to start. I.e. what is Kali Linux in your opinion, what it is used for, what is the intended audience for it and what knowledge they should have, what is a firewall for and what is endpoint security for. If you can answer all this you might already be able to answer your question yourself. If not we might correct you to point you into the right direction. Maybe in short: Kali Linux is not intended as a general purpose system for inexperienced users and this shows in the design of the system.

Comment: This is a strange question. Why do you think that it does not have a firewall, and what other Linux OS has endpoint protection?

Comment: This is looking like a homework question. Is it? Who is asking you to explain this?

Answer (score 3):

Kali Linux is to be mainly used as a penetration testing operating system, it doesn't need security such as firewalls and antivirus' as it may cause issues during testing or hamper in-built tools and exploits to the point where it just won't function.

This is not to say that Kali Linux doesn't have any such security, [here](https://kali.training/topic/exercise-chapter-7-securing-kali-networking/) is a tutorial on how to secure your Kali Linux network, including configuring a firewall.

However, I do not recommend storing private information and other sensitive data on your Kali-linux system, but instead, use it exclusively for testing and learning purposes. This way, you really shouldn't have a reason to search for security measures.

Comment: Updating a Kali Linux on a network where HTTP traffic is scanned for malware has interesting results, though.